# How to put an array in int but using scanf

Tags: c, arrays, printf, scanf

Soo the problem is putting an input for how many cases we have and how many time do i want to print it out in each cases

**EXAMPLE**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int T, N[ 10 ], start, go;

    scanf("%d", &T);
    for( start = 1 ; start <= T ; start++ ){
        scanf("%d", &N[ start ]);
    }   
    for( go = 1 ; go <= T ; go++ ){
        printf("Case #%d:\n", go);

        for( start = 1 ; start <= N[ start ] ; start++ ){
            printf("I will become a good boy.\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: To begin with, you remember that array indexes are zero-based? So for example an array of ten elements (like your array `N`) have indexes from `0` to `9` (inclusive).

Comment: As for your question, it's a little unclear what you're really asking about. Can you please elaborate? And for some specified input, what is the expected output? What is the actual output? Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Your inner for loop condition, should it be `N[go]`?

Comment: bit more explanation may be, at this point its a bit too brief to understand

Answer (score 1):

You need to dynamically allocate memory to N

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int T, start, go;
    int* N;

    printf("Please enter, How many entries do you want: \n");
    scanf("%d", &T);

    N = malloc(sizeof(int*) * T);

    for (start = 0; start < T; start++) 
    {
        scanf("%d", &N[start]);
    }

    for (go = 0; go < T; go++) 
    {
        printf("Case #%d:\n", go);

        for (start = 0; start < N[go]; start++) 
        {
            printf("I will become a good boy.\n");
        }
    }

    free(N);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From that code I assume T is the number of cases. Just dynamically allocate that array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int T, start, go;
   int* N;
   scanf("%d", &T);
   N = (int*) malloc(T * sizeof(int));
   for( start = 1 ; start <= T ; start++ )
   {
      scanf("%d", &N[ start ]);
   }
   for( go = 1 ; go <= T ; go++ )
   {
      printf("Case #%d:\n", go);
      for( start = 1 ; start <= N[ start ] ; start++ )
      {
         printf("I will become a good boy.\n"); 
      }
   }
   free(N);
   return 0;
}
```